# System.IO.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: vb.net

I have build an setup from my project. I have instal my project setup on the pc were i create the setup project an work, but when i try to instal on other pc the setup file and lunch the .exe i get an exception:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\adrian.moldovan\Desktop\New folder (2)\DataLogger\DataLogger\Resources\Cattura_3.jpg

I think i have a problem with the image location or image deploy.
I have use the image for a background image and i have use this code:

```
pBox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\adrian.moldovan\Desktop\New folder (2)\DataLogger\DataLogger\Resources\Cattura_3.jpg")
```

Have anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: check whether the image is present in the path or not `C:\Users\adrian.moldovan\Desktop\New folder (2)\DataLogger\DataLogger\Resources\Cattura_3.jpg`

Comment: Add the image as a resource in your project properties window. It'll then get built in which your installer etc.

Answer (score 0):

A FileNotFoundException means your file path is messed up or something. First, I would not expect both pc's to have the same user name. But, if they are the same, the easy way would be to go to file explorer, go to the picture file, hold shift + right click the file, go to 'copy file path' and paste that path into your code

Answer (score 0):

Add the image as a resource in your project properties window. It'll then get built in with your installer.